# Animated divs are morphing on screen

Tags: html, css

I've got a strange issue with some divs on my website http://www.words-by-design.co.uk. I am using a series of divs, which I have styled to be round and to animate with a mouse hover. In general, it works exactly as I want it to. However, occasionally, the first time you load the site the divs start as squares in the top of the page and move slowly over to their starting positions, whilst at the same time becoming round.

I'm completely stumped - any suggestions would be appreciated!

Here is the HTML for the animated portion of the page:

```
<div id='demoStrip'><div id='ballWrapper'>
    <div id='bounce' class='indexA'>
        <div class='ball' id='ball1'><p class='ballP'>Professional</p></div>
        <div class='ball' id='ball2'><p class='ballP'>Copy</p></div>
        <div class='ball' id='ball3'><p class='ballP'>For</p></div>
        <div class='ball' id='ball4'><p class='ballP'>Your</p></div>
        <div class='ball' id='ball5'><p class='ballP'>Needs</p></div>
    </div>
</div></div> <!-- End of demoStrip div -->
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/****************************
* Demo Strip and Animations *
****************************/

#demoStrip {
width: 960px;
height: 410px;
margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
/*background: #00cccc;*/
border-radius: 20px;
transition: all 4s;
}


#ballWrapper {
width: 900px;
height: 410px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.ball {
margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
border-radius: 200px;
background: #ffff99;
background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at center, #FFFF99 0%, #FFFF00     100%);
float: left;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #333333;
/*transition: margin-top 4s 0.1s ease;*/
transition: all 4s 0.1s;
}

p.ballP {
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: sans-serif;
margin: 0;
}

#ball1 {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin-top: 245px;
}

#ball2 {
width: 140px;
height: 140px;
margin-top: 185px;
}

#ball3 {
width: 130px;
height: 130px;
margin-top: 125px;
}

#ball4 {
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
margin-top: 65px;
}

#ball5 {
width: 110px;
height: 110px;
margin-top: 5px;
}

#bounce {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#ball1 p {
line-height: 150px;
}

#ball2 p {
line-height: 140px;
}


#ball3 p {
line-height: 130px;
}


#ball4 p {
line-height: 120px;
}


#ball5 p {
line-height: 110px;
}

/******************
* Index Animation *
******************/

.indexA:hover  #ball1 {
margin-top: 5px;
}

.indexA:hover #ball2 {
margin-top: 65px;
}

.indexA:hover #ball4 {
margin-top: 185px;
}

.indexA:hover #ball5 {
margin-top: 245px;
}
```

Many thanks!

Edit: I see this problem the most on Chrome version 35 for Windows 7.

Comment: I don't manage to replicate your issue

Comment: Same as above here, cannot reproduce the error on Chrome 35 MacOS X.
Make sure to edit the above and add the browser you're using and the version and which OS you're using.
Also keep in mind if you have any extensions/plugins loaded they might affect the behaviour of your page, I suggest you to test your pages in Incognito/Private mode with plugins switched off.

Comment: Also cannot replicate in chrome 35 on windows

Comment: It's a funny one, I can't always get it to occur, it seems to be totally random and as far as I can tell purely restricted to Chrome.